# GridView Row editing - change values

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to change values during edit in GridView. I'm using a method `Decrypt(object)` from codebehind.  It works for `Eval()`, but not work `Bind()`.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
          DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="entityDataSource1" >
  <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTab1" runat="server" 
                             Text='<%# Decrypt(Eval("Name")) %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="lblTab1" runat="server" 
                             Text='<%# Decrypt(Bind("Name")) %>' />
         </EditItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Why you are not using `Eval()` instead of `Bind()`?

Comment: Because it doesn't work in GridView's edit mode, e.g. I cannot change value in TextBox.

Comment: can you show me what your `Decrypt()` function is doing?

Comment: It just receives string, decrypt it using some other method and returns decrypted string. It doesn't matter in this case, it works for `Eval()`.

Comment: what I am suggest to you, before binding your **datasource** convert this field i.e. `Decrypt()` the data in data source and than after bind it with GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I need to do this, I usually set the `TextBox` `Text` property on the code behind on the `RowDataBound` event. It's like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound( Object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e ) {
    if( e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit ) {
        TextBox txt = ( TextBox )e.Row.FindControl( "lblTab1" );
        if( txt != null ) {
            DataRowView drv = ( DataRowView )e.Row.DataItem;
            txt.Text = Decrypt( drv["Name"].ToString() );
        }
    }
}
```

For this work, your `GridView` `EditIndex` property must be set with your actual index being edited.

Comment: in your answer there is no `Decrypt` done, also there is syntax error in the code.

Answer (score 0):

`Eval()` and `Bind()` are quite different creatures - `Eval()` is just shorthand for `DataBinder.Eval()` but `Bind()` is interpreted by the `ASP.NET` parser and broken into two parts - one for binding data to the control and the other for moving data from the control to your model.

This is described nicely in this old blog post: [How ASP.NET databinding deals with Eval and Bind statements](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/06/29/how-asp-net-databinding-deals-with-eval-and-bind-statements.aspx)

You don't mention what you are binding to; if you are binding to a business object then you could create a getter/setter property for an un-encrypted Name.  Alternatively you could provide an implementation of `OnRowUpdating`, and perform the `Decrypt` there.  (hint: update the `NewValues[]` member with the decrypted value).